# How to pass value from firebase database ValueEventListener?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

im quiet new in firebase database and android, I am create a method to count total size of db children, but it always return 0 when accessed outside onDataChange method, here my code

```
private int getChildSize() {
 final List<String> keys = new ArrayList<>();
 DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("profiles");
    ref.orderByChild("phoneNumber")
            .equalTo(phoneNumber)
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for(DataSnapshot item : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        keys.add(item.getKey());

                        Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: " + keys.size()); // more than 0
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

 return keys.size(); // return 0;
}
```

any ideas?

Comment: https://medium.com/@CodingDoug/why-are-firebase-apis-asynchronous-callbacks-promises-tasks-e037a6654a93

Answer (score 1):

Firebase calls are async, so you need the result to come back entierely before you can return it. What you can do is to call a method when the calll finishes:

```
private void getChildSize() {
 final List<String> keys = new ArrayList<>();
 DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("profiles");
    ref.orderByChild("phoneNumber")
            .equalTo(phoneNumber)
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for(DataSnapshot item : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        keys.add(item.getKey());

                        Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: " + keys.size()); // more than 0
                    }
                    finishedCounting(keys.size())

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

}

public void finishedCounting(int size){
//do something with size
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, any example how to do it?

Comment: edited the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Split that function:

put your `ValueEventListener` into a separate init function which does have no return type(void).

and  make `getChildSize` function only return the size.

Since your `ValueEventListener` is async it does not assign any values before the return statement is called.